# Java JFileChooser detail view sorting by date not running with Java 9

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I have in my program a customized `JFileChooser`. Calling the `JFileChooser` a detail view is shown where files are sorted by descending date.
Until Java 8 the sorting of files ran without problems. Since 2 weeks, we have Java 9 because we need some new functionalities. Under Java 9 the `JFileChooser` sort does not run anymore.

The Code is the follwing:

```
public class JFileChooserCustom extends JFileChooser {

....
....

JTable fileChoosertable = SwingUtils.getDescendantsOfType(JTable.class, this).get(0);          
TableColumn column3 = fileChoosertable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3);
column3.setPreferredWidth(120);
fileChoosertable.getRowSorter().toggleSortOrder(3);
fileChoosertable.getRowSorter().toggleSortOrder(3);
....
```

I called `toggledSortOrder` twice that the files wille be sorted by descending Dates.
Since Java 9 `toggleSortOrder` on the date column has no effect. I tried to implement an own rowsorter but it resulted in a many side effects. So, after sorting, the wrong files were selected. A implemented a new mouse listener which converted the selected rows numbers into the row numbers of the table model, but new side effects resulted.

Is there anaybody who knows a solution?

Comment: Can you invoke the toggleSortOrder() on a JTable you manually create? Or is it only a proper when you try to use SwingUtils on the file chooser?  What happens if you manually click on the table header to sort? Is your code executed on the EDT? Did you try wrapping the toggleSortOrder in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater()?  Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. Then people that use Java 8/9 can see if they notice a problem.

Comment: toggleSortOrder() on a manually created JTable runs. Only with filechooser it doesn't run. It runs also under Java 6 and Java 8. First under Java 9 it does'nt run. Under Java 9 a toggleSorter in the JFilechooser by programming has no effect, even if the column is another one then 'date', eg. witth the column of the file names. Manually clicking on the table header, it runs. invokleLater I still did not try, but I will try it.

Comment: I identified now the problem. The toggleSortOrder does not run because the table has no values (rowcount 0) until you have closed the filechooser by selection or cancel, that means, the table is fullfilled later than in earlier Java versions. So, I implemented a Thread which is another object than the customized JFileChooser which waits in a loop until the table has been filled and the toggleSortOrder runs. I do not unterstand why Oracle has modified this feature with Java 9 because this modification brought no improvement. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: `that means, the table is fullfilled later than in earlier Java versions.` - that is why I suggested wrapping the toggleSorOrder() in a SwingUtilties.invokeLater().